# Recursive copy function to copy data from socket to a file. What's wrong?

Tags: c, sockets, recursion, copy

My recursive copy function works on files, but not on socket to file. I believe it's because the files are "buffered" input/output. Sockets are not buffered right? So how would I make my copier work for both buffered/not buffered input output?

Here is my copier function.

```
/* file_download() - function to download a file.
 */
size_t file_download(int sockfd, FILE *fout) {
    char data[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int bytesRead, bytesWritten;
    static size_t total_bytes = 0;

    bytesRead = read(sockfd, data, sizeof(data));
    if(bytesRead > 0)
        bytesWritten = fwrite(data, 1, bytesRead, fout); /* Fixed this line */
    if(bytesWritten == bytesRead)
        return total_bytes;
    else
        total_bytes += bytesWritten;
    file_download(sockfd, fout);
}
```

What it does is only copies one byte of data when not buffered. But, it copies the whole thing when it is buffered input/output. Any help in resolving this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you do such a thing with recursion?

Comment: The *recursion* is what's wrong.

Comment: `fwrite(data, bytesRead, 1, fout)` should be `fwrite(data, 1, bytesRead, fout)`. Read the `fwrite` documentation.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll read the documentation for fwrite as well.

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code that actually works, but it was because of Antti Haapala letting me know that I had the two arguments backwords on fwrite... but this is what works.

```
/* file_download() - function to download a file.
 */
size_t file_download(int sockfd, FILE *fout) {
    char data[CHUNK_SIZE];
    int bytesRead, bytesWritten;
    static size_t total_bytes = 0;

    bytesRead = read(sockfd, data, sizeof(data));
    if(bytesRead > 0)
        bytesWritten = fwrite(data, 1, bytesRead, fout);
    if(bytesRead == 0)
        return total_bytes;
    else if(bytesWritten == bytesRead)
        total_bytes += bytesWritten;
    else
        return -1;
    file_download(sockfd, fout);
}
```

Comment: You should not use recursion for non-recursive problems. This code does not scale to large files. Iterate.